# Python mysql request

Tags: python, mysql

Обьясни пожалуйста в что делает символ ` при запросе в бд

Есть такая функиця для запроса в бд

```
def query_DB(sql, params=()):
    try:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, passwd, db)
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR CONNECT DB >>>> ' + str(e))
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = []
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
        for row in cursor:
            result.append(row)
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR query_DB:  ' + str(e))
    finally:
        conn.close()
        return result
```

Допустим есть таблица books колонки test, test1, test2 имеют значение , а колонка test3 = None

При таком запросе

```
query_DB("SELECT test, test1, test2, test3 FROM books WHERE id=%s", (book_id,))
```

возникает Exception

Такой запрос отрабатывает нормально

```
query_DB("SELECT test, test1, test2, `test3` FROM books WHERE id=%s", (book_id,))
```

те содержимое из test3 отдается как None и не возникает Exception. 
Обьясните пожалуйста что в моем случаи дает экранирование test3 и почему в первом случаи возникает исключение?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85452/discussion-on-question-by---python-mysql-request).